# How to click third link of contents box of this wikipedia article?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, linked-list

I am trying to target 3rd link

```
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket");
WebElement contents = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='toc']")); //moving webdriver scope to contents
List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName(“a”)); 
contents.click(allLinks.get(2));
```

Is my code correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think the last line should be changed as,

```
allLinks.get(2).click();
```

Using this, you will be able to click the 3rd link element.

Comment: It will click second link of webpage, but I am targeting second link on "contents" box.

Comment: I thought you are trying to click that element.